# Drool Plugin not found in Plugins section of Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, drools

I need to add Drool plugin to Intellij Idea 2018.3.1.

But when I Tried to add the plugin, Drool plugin is not found in the plugin section.
File -> Settings-> Plugins

Can't we add Drool plugin in to Intellij?

Answer (score 0):

The drools plugin comes bundled in the Ultimate edition. I don't think it's available in the community edition.

If you're using the ultimate edition you should find it under settings - plugins. Click on the installed tab, and type drools in the search box.